# Transform data when parsing a JSON string using Dart

Tags: dart

I'm using the `parse()` function provided in `dart:json`. Is there a way to transform the parsed data using `parse()`? I'm thinking of something similar to the `reviver` argument when parsing JSON using JavaScript:

```dart
JSON.parse(text[, reviver])
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `parse()` function in `dart:json` takes a callback as an arg that you can use to transform the parsed data. For example, you may prefer to express a date field as a DateTime object, and not as a list of numbers representing the year, month and day. Specify a ‘reviver’ function as a second argument to parse.

This function is called once for each object or list property parsed, and the return value of the reviver function is used instead of the parsed value:

```dart
import 'dart:json' as json;

void main() {
  var jsonPerson = '{"name" : "joe", "date" : [2013, 10, 3]}';

  var person = json.parse(jsonPerson, (key, value) {
    if (key == "date") {
      return new DateTime(value[0], value[1], value[2]);
    }
    return value;
  });

  person['name'];             // 'joe'
  person['date'] is DateTime; // true
}
```